# Unable to access “222 GB Volume”

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 along with windows 8.1. After installing ubuntu I'm unable to
boot windows and unable to mount my 222 GB volume. I got following error when i tried to
mount my 222 GB volume:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/ankit/4EA0C653A0C64167: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/ankit/4EA0C653A0C64167"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (495691775): Invalid argument
```

HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).

```
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
```

Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
    partition (e.g. `/dev/sda`, not `/dev/sda1`)? Or the other way around?

Comment: did you install the ntfs-progs package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)